# Refresh div which includes sprintf

Tags: javascript, php

I have two php files. The first is named index.php, the second one is named data.php. I tried to get the contents from the file data.php into index.php. Initially it gave me an error using the include_once statement but I now got it to work with:

```
<?php $str = sprintf(include_once ("/www/index1.php"));
   echo $str; ?>
```

Now, I want this part to refresh every minute without reloading the complete page.

I tried inserting into index.php the following:

```
<!-- Div refresh function -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
    $("#data").load("/www/data.php"); //Load the content into the div
}), 60000);
</script>

<div id="data"><?php $str = sprintf(include_once ("/www/data.php"));
   echo $str; ?></div>
```

I admit, it looks a bit wrong and guess what, it doesn't work. I this is because it tries to load data.php in de script-part and afterwards I try to include the file again in the < div>-statement. I can't get it to work.

I have looked a various examples but can't find any using the sprintf function. I must admit that my knowledge of java, ajax and or json is not great.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I think you ran in to a problem and headed down a road that compounded it. Could you backtrack to the original problem and clarify your question.

Comment: @dan08 I got some errors using just the include statement. I changed my code to sprintf (first code example). It than run correct on the index.php webpage.
Later on, I tried to implement this update js-script so I changed it to '<div id="data"><?php $str = sprintf(include_once ("/www/data.php"));
   echo $str; ?></div>'. Is this more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a front end script. If you want to load something via ajax, you should know its based on js. While js is based on web browser. So make sure you can access that url from browser first.

You can access `/www/data.php` from php, but if you want to load it in js, make sure it can be visit from web first. How can you visit your `index.php`?

If you can visit `index.php` via `http://xx.com/index.php`, then change `$("#data").load("/www/data.php");` to `$("#data").load("http://xx.com/data.php");`, you will find it works.

---

Update: Based on your comment, try `$("#data").load("data.php");`

Also, you can use developer tools to debug it. If js gets error, you will see it.

Comment: given in the question, `index.php` and `data.php` in the same directory, he  should be able to `$("#data").load("data.php");` as relative to the current page, without need to know the full URI

Comment: you are right. But it will be helpful for him to understand whats the difference between js & php when includes files.

Comment: I know that php is done on the server side and any js is done on the client (or browser) side. Also, php is executed once before the page is then displayed to the browser. Hence I was looking to update it the way I did. Both files are running on my homeserver at the moment which is Linux-based, hence the www/ folder where the files indeed both are stored.
So in this case (files both in same directory) I can use data.php instead of the full path which will be 192.168.0.10/data.php if I understand correct.
I tried to implement this change but nothing is updating (yet)

Comment: Actually your answer in combination with Tomer W's suggestion did the job. I just had to open the correct index.php page again as I was working in a copy of the original to not damage the working one. oops :S

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something wrong.

What you need to do:

1. Create file with needful data (for example `data.php`).
2. Create file for loading data-file (for example `loader.php`). If you are using php (I see you are), you can `file_get_contents` for `data.php` and then `echo` it.
3. On page, where you want to get your data, use something like this:

JS:

```
function loadData() {
    $("#data-container").load("loader.php", function() {
        console.log("Load was performed.");
    });
}

loadData(); // load first then refreshing every 1 min:
setInterval(loadData, 60000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="data-container"></div>
```

So, what all of this doing here?

- First, script on your page create request to `loader.php`;
- Second, `loader.php` executes (I hope your server execute php, huh?) and get content of `data.php` (so in this context `data.php` can have any file name extention; `data.txt`, `data.log`, etc); then it `echo` that content;
- Third, script on your page get echoed (by `loader.php`) content of `data.php` and paste it in your `#data-container`.

These steps repeat again every 1 min.

**Note:** If `data.php` in your context is not a programming code (just some data), you can create just `data.html` and load it directly in jQuery script. It's not need any php-loader files, etc.

Comment: I will try and report back. The errors I was referring to initially where due to the fact I used file_get_contents. It didn't pass the data correctly and my variables where all missing on my index.php. That's why I went ahead and start using the sprintf function and that solved the passing-the-data problem...

Comment: I keep your suggestion in mind. For now, the first submitted answer did the job so I went ahead and ticket it. Thanks for your input though!